# Accessing files on a Windows 7 computer from a Windows 10 Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions, network-shares

I have Windows 7 laptop that I want to be able to copy files from onto a Windows 10 laptop on a regular basis. I've shared the folders on the Win 7 laptop and can see the computer and shares on the Win 10 system however when I select the shared folder I get a message saying I don't have permission to access it. I've set permissions on the Win 7 system giving everyone all access.

How can I access files/folders on the Win 7 system from my Win 10 system?

Comment: Have you checked [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+file+sharing+on+windows+10&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)?

Comment: The problem is specifically with the C drive root folder. I've checked google / microsoft and all I get are references to Windows 10 and or Homegroups. And homegroups are nolonger supported in Windows 10

Comment: Does the Win7 user require a password? You can't share files with a Win10 machine if your Win7 user does not require a password for login.

Comment: Check the permissions of Everyone to see if it has the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have same local account on both Laptops and this account member of Local Administrator's Group.

Also When you  MAP Drive from one laptop to another make sure you use 
Login Name: PCNAME\USERNAME